in ensemble the resulting model is nonlinear even if the base model is linear?
I have this doubt, in the case an ensemble of linear basic models I am convinced (but I do not know the exact mathematical explanation for this) that the resulting ensamble works only for a linear space. On the other hand, in case there are also nonlinear base models present (e.g., 50%) what would happen? the resulting model is nonlinear?

It depends crucially on how your "ensembling" works.
For instance, suppose you have two linear models, $y=a_1+b_1x$ and $y=a_2+b_2x$, and the ensembling picks one of the two models depending on $x$, e.g., in a CART with linear models at the bottom. The result is nonlinear in $x$, and if you have more than two models, you can get as nonlinear as you want.
Conversely, if "ensembling" just means putting an instance with its $x$ into all linear models and taking a weighted average of the prediction without regard to $x$, then the end result is linear in $x$, and actually equivalent to a single linear model, with the parameters being the weighted averages of the component parameters.
